# How to convert textbox to multiline in TFS

Tags: multiline, tfs-2015

I have a single line textbox in TFS named "Customer Request." I wanted to convert this field from single line to multi line (even though not a rich text field). Is that possible because I searched and searched in google but found no related case. Here's the screenshot below of the field that must be updated to multiline.
[image]

Comment: Where are you using the single line textbox? Customize workitem? Could you add a related screenshot?

Comment: I am using the single line textbox on Customer Request field and yes this is a Customized workitem. I have uploaded the sceenshot on my question above.

Comment: Have update my reply, please see below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want a field control with single line that will allow for the entry of multiple lines instead of using a rich-text format filed such as **Html** & **HtmlFiledControl**.

> **HtmlFieldControl:** Used to display multiline, rich-text format of fields that have a field data type of HTML.

Without changing the [Data types](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/define-modify-work-item-fields) and [Type attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243845(v=vs.100).aspx), it's impossible to achieve it. For example, as a workaround you could use a **plaintext** field with the **HtmlFieldControl** type attribute. You will get below screenshot in your custom work item:

[image]

However, which does not give you the ability to retain formatting in report.  The text is stored in the database **without any line controls**, so it is just one big string. If you want to keep the formatting in report, afraid the only way is using  a rich text field.